# Rotation in 'FactoMineR' package

Tags: r, rotation, factor-analysis

Thanks in advance.  I've used the 'PCA' function from the 'FactoMineR' package to obtain principal component scores.  I've tried reading through the [package details](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/FactoMineR/FactoMineR.pdf) and similar questions on this forum but can't figure out the code to rotate the extracted components (either orthogonal or oblique).

I know the 'princomp' function and the 'principal' function in the 'psych' package have rotating abilities but I really like the ability in 'PCA' to scale the variables to unit-variance.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thank you.

Comment: Ah, PCA and rotation again. Perhaps this post will be of some help to you. http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/612/is-psychprincipal-function-still-pca-when-using-rotation

Comment: Thanks for the link.  I know the particular packages discussed have rotation, but they don't don't have the ability to natively scale variables or include supplemental data like 'PCA'.  I did some other reading and found that 'prcomp' can both rotate and scale, but can't include supplemental info.  Is there a one-stop shop for all of these abilities in one function?  Thanks.

Comment: Any update on this? I want to do an oblique rotation on results from mixed data (numeric + categorical). Both FAMD and and PCAmix from PCAmixdata package seem to support mixed data, but couldnt find a good way of doing an oblique rotation.

Answer (score 3):

IIUC:

```
library(FactoMineR)
data(iris)
Iris <- iris[,1:4]
res <- PCA(Iris, graph=F)
#rotation
t(apply(res$var$coord, 1, function(x) {x/sqrt(res$eig[,1])}))
                  Dim.1      Dim.2      Dim.3      Dim.4
Sepal.Length  0.5210659 0.37741762 -0.7195664 -0.2612863
Sepal.Width  -0.2693474 0.92329566  0.2443818  0.1235096
Petal.Length  0.5804131 0.02449161  0.1421264  0.8014492
Petal.Width   0.5648565 0.06694199  0.6342727 -0.5235971

#check
prcomp(Iris, scale=T)
Rotation:
                    PC1         PC2        PC3        PC4
Sepal.Length  0.5210659 -0.37741762  0.7195664  0.2612863
Sepal.Width  -0.2693474 -0.92329566 -0.2443818 -0.1235096
Petal.Length  0.5804131 -0.02449161 -0.1421264 -0.8014492
Petal.Width   0.5648565 -0.06694199 -0.6342727  0.5235971
```

An alternative line of code, if you wish to obtain loadings from `PCA` object:

```
sweep(res$var$coord, 2, sqrt(res$eig[,1]),'/')
```

Comment: How can I apply varimax rotation?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same need here. I want to do a rotation with `FactominR`, but the answer above just gives me the original loadings.

http://factominer.free.fr/question/FAQ.html

```
sweep(
  res.pca$var$coord,
  2, 
  sqrt(res.pca$eig[1:ncol(res.pca$var$coord), 1]),
  FUN = "/"
)
```